# Totalcross - Whiteboard inicia traço com diferença do ponto inicialmente pressionado

Tags: totalcross

Estou usando o componente Whiteboard, para assinaturas, porem ao fazer um traço, ele desenha com uma diferença do ponto inicial onde pressionei a tela, fazendo um risco na vertical de aproximadamente 30 pontos, para dai fazer o traço pressionado na tela, Como resolvo isso???

Comment: A classe `Whiteboard` é aberta, vai junto no SDK. Sinta-se a vontade para derivá-la ou criar uma classe nova baseada nela. Só um minuto para uma resposta mais completa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     case PenEvent.PEN_DOWN:
        pe = (PenEvent)event;
        oldX = pe.x;
        oldY = pe.y;
        yIni = pe.y;       <=======
        drawTo(gImg, pe.x,pe.y); // after
        if (gScr != null) drawTo(gScr,pe.x,pe.y);
        getParentWindow().setGrabPenEvents(this); // guich@tc100: redirect all pen events to here, bypassing other processings
        if (Settings.isOpenGL) te = addTimer(100);
        break;
     case PenEvent.PEN_DRAG:
        pe = (PenEvent)event;
        if (yIni>0) {                
            yDif = yIni -pe.y;         
            yIni = 0;                 
        }
        drawTo(gImg, pe.x,pe.y + yDif); // before
        if (gScr != null) drawTo(gScr, pe.x, pe.y + yDif);  
        oldX = pe.x;
        oldY = pe.y + yDif;
        if (!Settings.isOpenGL) Window.safeUpdateScreen(); // important at desktop!
        break;
```

Ajustei a rotina dessa forma, calculei a diferença do pe.y do evento PEN_DOWN com o pe.y do evento PEN_DRAG e apliquei ela no pe.y para traçar a linha.

Answer (score 2):

A classe `Whiteboard` trabalha com o conceito de vários pequenos traços. A cada momento, ele captura o ponto onde está o toque e desenha uma reta em comparação ao ponto anterior.

A magia desse conceito de pequenos traços na tela está no método `drawTo` dentro da `Whiteboard`; dado um novo ponto, conhecendo o ponto anterior, desenhe a linha:

```
private void drawTo(Graphics g, int pex, int pey)
{
    g.drawLine(oldX,oldY,pex,pey); // guich@580_34: draw directly on screen
    if (thick)
    {
        g.drawLine(oldX+1,oldY+1,pex+1,pey+1);
        g.drawLine(oldX-1,oldY-1,pex-1,pey-1);
        g.drawLine(oldX+1,oldY+1,pex-1,pey-1);
        g.drawLine(oldX-1,oldY-1,pex+1,pey+1);
    }
}
```

> Nota: caso esteja ligado para fazer um desenho grosso, ele fará um conjunto adicional de linha paralelas, conforme visto no `if (thick)`.

No caso do primeiro toque (evento do tipo `PEN_DOWN`), ele acaba que desenha um *segmento de zero pixels*, o que vira um ponto no tela:

```
public onEvent(Event event)
{
    PenEvent pe;
    switch (event.type)
    {
    [...]
    case PenEvent.PEN_DOWN:
        pe = (PenEvent)event;
        oldX = pe.x;
        oldY = pe.y;
        drawTo(gImg, pe.x,pe.y); // after
        if (gScr != null) drawTo(gScr,pe.x,pe.y);
        getParentWindow().setGrabPenEvents(this); // guich@tc100: redirect all pen events to here, bypassing other processings
        if (Settings.isOpenGL) te = addTimer(100);
        break;
    [...]
} [fim do onEvent]
```

Ao arrastar o toque (evento do tipo `PEN_DRAG`), a cada captura de arraste o `Whiteboard` fará um traço a partir do toque anterior até o toque atual:

```
public onEvent(Event event)
{
    PenEvent pe;
    switch (event.type)
    {
    [...]
    case PenEvent.PEN_DRAG:
        pe = (PenEvent)event;
        drawTo(gImg, pe.x,pe.y); // before
        if (gScr != null) drawTo(gScr,pe.x,pe.y);
        oldX = pe.x;
        oldY = pe.y;
        if (!Settings.isOpenGL) Window.safeUpdateScreen(); // important at desktop!
        break;
    [...]
} [fim do onEvent]
```

No caso, a sensibilidade de onde o sistema pega o ponto do clique (`pe.x` e `pe.y`) depende do seu dedo e também do aparelho. Até o momento atual e os testes realizados, a precisão tem sido bem satisfatória.

Answer (score 2):

```
public onEvent(Event event) 
{
    PenEvent pe; 
    switch (event.type) 
    { 
    [...] 
    case PenEvent.PEN_DOWN: 
        pe = (PenEvent)event; 
        oldX = pe.x; 
        oldY = pe.y;
        drawTo(gImg, pe.x,pe.y); // after 
        if (gScr != null) drawTo(gScr,pe.x,pe.y);
      //  getParentWindow().setGrabPenEvents(this); // guich@tc100: redirect all //pen events to here, bypassing other processings
        if (Settings.isOpenGL) te = addTimer(100);
        break;
    [...]
} [fim do onEvent]
```

Inclui a classe no projeto e após depurar, comentei a linha com o comando

```
getParentWindow().setGrabPenEvents(this);
```

e funcionou corretamente conforme o esperado.

O que deveria ter feito para que não fosse necessário comentar essa linha???

Comment: Foi só a nível de java/depuração? Ou confirmou no dispositivo também?

Comment: Só a nivel de depuração, no dispositivo não funcionou, perde a função de fazer o  traço.

Comment: Hmmm... Então você está falando que, no original, a deteção do toque inicial estava problemática, porém quando você removeu o `setGrapPenEvents` em tese corrige o toque inicial, porém não consegue detectar arrastos?

Comment: Inicia o traço do ponto certo, porém em um momento ele perde a função de riscar, assumindo a função do toque para seleção.

Comment: Deve ser efeito colateral de não ter mais o `setGrabPenEvents`... Vou tentar dar umas simuladas, depois do experimento eu volto

Comment: Inclui uma resposta com um ajuste para atender a minha necessidade. Analisando o código que colei entendera melhor o que esta ocorrendo.